# CircleCI build getting "Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.1"

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to build an Android app on CircleCI using this **circle.yml** file

```
machine:
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
  environment:
    # Java options
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

dependencies:
  pre:
    # Download and install latest(26.0.2) sdk-tools revision
    - wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
    - mkdir sdk
    - unzip -d sdk sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip

    # Accepts SDK licenses
    - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"


    # Install Android SDKs and additional repositories
    - echo y | sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --channel=2 "build-tools;25.0.3" "platform-tools" "tools"
    - echo y | sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --channel=2 "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;google_play_services"

test:
    override:
    # Generate a debug-apk
    - ./gradlew assembleAppseeOffDebug -PdisablePreDex

    # Copy the generated apk files to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/apk/ $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS

    # Copy the test results to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

The problem is that during the gradle build phase, I got this error

```
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      file:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
      https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.pom
      https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.0.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.1.jar
```

Is there any sdk dependency that I'm not declaring in circle.yml file?

Comment: Can I use CircleCI without gms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the executor (oraclejdk8),that does not had the correct Android SDK and Google repositories installed.

I solved the problem by migrating from CircleCI 1.0 to 2.0 and setting [bitriseio/docker-android:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitriseio/docker-android/) - which has the correct repositories installed by default - as docker image.

Here's my final **config.yml**

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:

    working_directory: /opt/working

    docker:
      - image: bitriseio/docker-android:latest

    environment:
      # Java options
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
      GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Accepts License
          command: echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"

      - run:
          name: Assemble & Test
          command: ./gradlew assembleDebug testDebugUnitTest

      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports/tests/
          destination: tests_reports/

      - store_test_results:
          path: "app/build/test-results/testDebugUnitTest/"

      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/
          destination: apks/
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your 2.0 config.yml file? I had circleCI building my Android app just fine until I updated to the latest gradle plugin and now getting the same error posted here.

I'm following the guide to convert to 2.0 but not sure about the docker image note you mention..

Comment: @jpage4500 I added the **config.yml**

Comment: thanks for posting this! I'm learning this 2.0 configuration and through trial and error hopefully can get my builds running again! I did notice that my first attempt failed with "* no working_directory" error. I'll post my full working config.yml script once done if it helps anyone else